# Missing intermediate records from the CSV file while importing it in to My SQL by using python program

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I am using below python program to read the CSV file continuously and import its latest new records in to My SQL Database. The problem is missing of intermediate random records. For Example if CSV contain 100 records then MySQL DB contains less number of records

This works fine for a static CSV file, e.g. one where all the data to be processed and is already contained within the CSV file...

CSV file is updated by continuously by another application.
I want to read that CSV file whenever there is change in it (new records appended in it), and then copy its latest records in to MySQL DB table.

```
import csv
import time
import mysql.connector


def csv_cycle(filex):
    with open(filex) as fd:
        x = csv.reader(fd)
        while True:
            for r in x:
                yield tuple(r)
            fd.seek(fd.tell())
            fd.readline()  # skips the header


file = 'A.csv'

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', user='root', passwd='admin$23', port=3306, database='sbo_alarms',
                               auth_plugin='mysql_native_password')
mycursor = mydb.cursor()
sql_insert = '''INSERT INTO alarms (Previous_State,Current_State,AlarmText,Priority,Category,TimeStamp)
VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)'''

for row in csv_cycle(file):
    try:
        mycursor.execute(sql_insert, row)
        mydb.commit()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

Comment: What is the purpose of `fd.seek(fd.tell())`?

Comment: This is because of the line `fd.readline()  # skips the header`.  it will skip (sometimes?) the first line of newly added records.

Answer (score 0):

I have done some testing.

Start creating a `A.csv` file with 2 lines.

When starting your script the 2 records are read, and the script waits for next input.

Doing `TYPE A.csv >>A.csv`, which effectively doubles the number of lines in the CSV file, result in these 2 extra lines being read.

Repeating the `TYPE A.csv >>A.csv`, results in 8 lines.

Again repeating the `TYPE A.csv >>A.csv`, results in 16,32,64 lines.

But when doin it again i repeatedly get a response that 167 lines are processed. (and not the expected 128).

End of the output looks like:

```
156 ('1', '2', '3')
157 ('a', 'b', 'c')
158 ('1', '2', '3')
159 ('a', 'b', 'c')
160 ('1', '2', '3')
161 ('a', 'b', 'c')
162 ('1', '2', '3')
163 ('a', 'b', 'c')
164 ('1', '2', '3')
165 ('a', 'b', 'c')
166 ('1', '2', '3')
167 ('a', '')
```

I started with `A.csv` containing:

```
"a","b","c"
1,2,3
```

And the code I used (removed the database, and add echo to screen of processed records:

```
import csv
import time
import mysql.connector


def csv_cycle(filex):
    with open(filex) as fd:
        x = csv.reader(fd)
        while True:
            for r in x:
                yield tuple(r)
            #fd.seek(fd.tell())
            #fd.readline()  # skips the header

file = 'A.csv'

i=1
for row in csv_cycle(file):
    try:
        print(i, row)
        i=i+1
    except Exception as e:
        print('.')
        print(e)
```

Comment: I guess that `TYPE A.csv >>A.csv` starts to read the file incompletely if it is larger than a particular size, then writes the read block to stdoud and reads the next block which may then already contain the data it has written to the file moments before. So this command may produce a file of unpredictable line count where last line may be incomplete.